# debug magic function in ipython console

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, pdb, jupyter-console

I have a file called foo.py. In that file I have a bunch of functions and I would like to debug one of them, called `foo.bar` by setting a breakpoint but not hardcoding it using `set_trace`. I am working in an IPython console and I know there is a `%debug` magic function that can be used for this purpose with the syntax:

```
%debug [--breakpoint FILE:LINE]
```

So I try

```
%debug --breakpoint foo.py:10
```

to set the breakpoint at line 10. However, how do I actually execute the code then so that IPython recognizes the breakpoint? Doing

```
import foo
foo.bar()
```

does not work as the breakpoint is simply skipped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this:

```
from foo import bar
%debug --breakpoint /path/to/foo.py:10 bar()
```

This will import `bar` into the namespace and run it with the breakpoint on line 10 of the module.